# Find rate of convergence for $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: taylor-expansion, rate-of-convergence

We can use Taylor series to expand $\sqrt{x}$
$$
\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}(x-n) - \frac{1}{4n^{3/2}}(x-n)^2 + ...
$$

The solution provided to me uses expansion point around $\sqrt{n}$. And then we are supposed to substitute $x=n+1$

$$
\sqrt{n+1} = \sqrt n + \frac{1}{2\sqrt n}(n + 1 - n) + ...
$$

And we arrive at

$$
\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n = (\sqrt n + \frac{1}{2\sqrt n}(n + 1 - n) + ...) - \sqrt n 
\\ = O(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) 
$$

What I don't understand is how the expansion point is chosen.

Comment: Alternatively, rewrite the generic term as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n + 1}} \sim O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) .$$

Comment: i believe the expansion point is actually $x$ and the function evaluated at the expansion point (first term in the taylor series) is $\sqrt{x}$, which means its just the general Taylor series, its not really chose

Comment: Doesn't Taylor series start with $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(a)(x-a)^2/2! + ...$ so the derivatives can be evaluated without input $x$? EDIT: What I mean is that $a$ is not provided in the input

Comment: @phoxd So $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, $a = n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand the series at anywhere you like (that make sense). For example, you can even try at $\sqrt{n + 1}$:

$$\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{n+1} + \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} (x - n - 1) + \dfrac{1}{4(n+1)^{3/2}}(x - n - 1)^2 + \cdots$$

and sub $x = n$:

$$\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n+1} + \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} (-1) + \cdots$$

$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} + \cdots = O(1/\sqrt{n+1}) \rightarrow O(1/\sqrt{n})$$

That $n$ goes to infinity as you stated.

It's just for your convenience to expand the series at $x = n$.

Comment: So do we need to choose appropriately where to expand to get to the rate of convergence?

Comment: I guess yes... like expanding around $x > 0$ because $\sqrt{< 0}$ is not real; and you might not want to handle the mess around $0$. Anyway, to pick the number that appears in the problem -- $n$ in this case -- to evaluate is always worth trying.